# $R(A)$ is dense in $Y$ if and only if $A^*$ is injective

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I have a problem with the proof of the following theorem

If $V,Y$ are Banach spaces and $A\in L(V,Y)$, then $R(A)$ is dense in $Y$ if and only if the adjoint operator $A^*$ is injective.

The proof goes like this. "$\Leftarrow$" Suppose that $cl (R(A))\neq Y$. Then we can find $y^*\in Y^*$, $y^*\neq 0$ such that $\langle y^*, Av\rangle=0$ for all $v$ in V…  Why can we find such  $y^*$?

Comment: It's the Hahn-Banach theorem. If $cl(R(A))\neq Y$, there is some $y\neq0$ in $Y$ such that $y\notin cl(R(A))$. Then the Hahn-Banach theorem furnishes a $y^*\in Y^*$ such that $y^*(y)\neq0$ while $cl(R(A)\subset \ker(y^*)$.  This result is theorem 3.5 in Rudin's *Functional Analysis*.

Comment: A few things I need to ask about. First of all, we have to use the fact that every Banach space is locally convex. Since $cl(R(A))\neq Y$ we may find $y\neq 0$ which is not in $cl(R(A))$. Oherwise, if $y=0$ then $y\in cl(R(A))$ automatically. Now, we can use separation theorem and obtain the existance of $y^*$ such that $\langle y^*,y\rangle\neq 0$. This is what I deduced from your comment. Why do write that $cl(R(A))\subset ker(y^*)$?

Comment: Because that's how you show that $A^*$ is not injective.  $cl(R(A))\subset\ker(y^*)$ is the same thing as $\langle y^*,Av\rangle=0$ for all $v\in V$.

Comment: I'll write an answer explaining my thoughts.

Comment: Ok, but how do you obtain the inclusion? Taking into account that $A^*$ is adjoint operator I have $$ker A=\bigcap_{\|\varphi^*\|=1}ker A^*\varphi*.$$ What to do with the range?

Comment: That result doesn't help us calculate $\ker A^*$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main result at play is this:

> Let $X$ be a locally convex space, and let $M$ be a proper subspace of $X$.  If $x$ is not in the closure of $M$, then there is some $f\in X^*$ such that $ f(M)=\{0\}$ while $f(x)\neq0$.

Indeed, if we apply the Hahn-Banach separation theorem to the compact set $\{x\}$ and the closed convex set $cl(M)$, we obtain some $f\in X^*$ such that $f(\{x\})$ and $f(cl(M))$ are disjoint.  But then $f(cl(M))$ is a proper subspace of $\mathbb R$ (or $\mathbb C$), and thus $f(cl(M))=\{0\}$.  Since $f(cl(M))$ and $f(\{x\})$ are disjoint, we know $f(x)\neq0$.

Now we apply this result to your problem.  If $cl(R(A))\neq Y$, there is some non-zero $y\in Y$ such that $y\notin cl(R(A))$.  Now, the mentioned results guarantees the existence of some $y^*\in Y^*$ such that $y^*(y)\neq0$ but $y^*(cl(R(A)))=\{0\}$.  Thus $\langle y^*,Av\rangle=0$ for all $v\in V$.

Comment: Now, it's very clear to me. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome.  Glad I could help!